# I am simply not able to bring the PAHO / Eclipse MQTT Android Service into an Android Studio project

Tags: java, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am simply not able to bring the PAHO / Eclipse MQTT Android Service into an Android Studio project.  It says "A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'."   I have added the required dependencies in the build.gragle(module) file.
Bellow, I will add the full build.gradle file. including the full error.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mqqttestapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-snapshots/"
    }
}



dependencies {


    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.1.0'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'

}
```

*error*

```
Build file 'C:\Users\*****\MQQTtestApp\app\build.gradle' line: 30

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'maven' was added by build file 'app\build.gradle'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GOTO settings.gradle and **replace**

```
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
```

**with**

```
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
```

That installed MQTT lib into my project.